# Ansible: Creating report with dictionary key and sub-elements in list of dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, ansible, nested, nested-loops

I have a dictionary.  Each element contains a list dictionaries.  I would like to create a report
containing the keys of the primary dictionary and the subelements of each of the subordinate dictionaries.

The data looks like this:

```
vars:
    array_info:
      purefa_info:
        hosts:
          devhost:
            volumes:
            - {hostgroup: null, lun: 10, volume: 'vol_0'}
            - {hostgroup: null, lun: 11, volume: 'vol_1'}
          prdhost:
            volumes:
            - {hostgroup: prodhosts, lun: 12, volume: vol_2}
            - {hostgroup: prodhosts, lun: 13, volume: vol_3}
```

I'm looking for this sort of thing:

```
devhost,vol_0,10,
devhost,vol_0,11,
prdhost,vol_2,12,prodhosts
prdhost,vol_3,13,prodhosts
```

I can get the name of the array_info.purefa_info.hosts in the first task.
and the sub-elementss with the second task.  But I've not been able to figure
out how to get them together.

```
---
- name: recurse and report dicts
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    array_info:
      purefa_info:
        hosts:
          devhost:
            volumes:
            - {hostgroup: null, lun: 10, volume: 'vol_0'}
            - {hostgroup: null, lun: 11, volume: 'vol_1'}
          prdhost:
            volumes:
            - {hostgroup: prodhosts, lun: 12, volume: vol_2}
            - {hostgroup: prodhosts, lun: 13, volume: vol_3}

  tasks:

    - name: I can get the key when I use "with_dict" but volumes is a list of dict
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key, item.value['volumes'] }}"
      with_dict:  "{{ array_info.purefa_info.hosts }}"

    - name: I can get the low level bits I want using sub-elements, but not the "key"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1.volume }},{{ item.1.lun }},{{ item.1.hostgroup }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ array_info.purefa_info.hosts }}"
        - volumes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close with the `subelements` approach.

I modified your code a bit to leverage [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops), and the [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html) and [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_filter.html) filters.  This allows you to iterate over the sub-elements while maintaining a reference to the original `key`.

```
---
- name: recurse and report dicts
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    array_info:
      purefa_info:
        hosts:
          devhost:
            volumes:
              - { hostgroup: null, lun: 10, volume: "vol_0" }
              - { hostgroup: null, lun: 11, volume: "vol_1" }
          prdhost:
            volumes:
              - { hostgroup: prodhosts, lun: 12, volume: vol_2 }
              - { hostgroup: prodhosts, lun: 13, volume: vol_3 }

  tasks:
    - name: Loop over dict and subelements
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }},{{ item.1.volume }},{{ item.1.lun }}"
      loop: "{{ array_info.purefa_info.hosts | dict2items | subelements('value.volumes') }}"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent and concise example of
chaining the filters.  I have several applications for this approach.
You've opened a window; I'm, jumping!

Comment: I know the feeling and glad I could help :)

If the answer works for you, please mark it as accepted.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The iteration with subelements

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.0.key }},{{ item.1.volume }},{{ item.1.lun }},{{ item.1.hostgroup }}"
    loop: "{{ array_info.purefa_info.hosts|
              dict2items|
              subelements('value.volumes') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: devhost,vol_0,10,
  msg: devhost,vol_1,11,
  msg: prdhost,vol_2,12,prodhosts
  msg: prdhost,vol_3,13,prodhosts
```

Optionally, use *json_query* first and create the dictionary

```yaml
  hosts_dict_query: >
    [].[key,
        value.volumes[].[volume,
                         to_string(lun),
                         not_null(hostgroup,'')]]
  hosts_dict: "{{ dict(array_info.purefa_info.hosts|
                       dict2items|
                       json_query(hosts_dict_query)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  hosts_dict:
    devhost:
    - [vol_0, '10', '']
    - [vol_1, '11', '']
    prdhost:
    - [vol_2, '12', prodhosts]
    - [vol_3, '13', prodhosts]
```

The below iteration gives the same result

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.0.key }},{{ item.1|join(',') }}"
    loop: "{{ hosts_dict|
              dict2items|
              subelements('value') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    array_info:
      purefa_info:
        hosts:
          devhost:
            volumes:
            - {hostgroup: null, lun: 10, volume: vol_0}
            - {hostgroup: null, lun: 11, volume: vol_1}
          prdhost:
            volumes:
            - {hostgroup: prodhosts, lun: 12, volume: vol_2}
            - {hostgroup: prodhosts, lun: 13, volume: vol_3}

    hosts_dict_query: >
      [].[key,
          value.volumes[].[volume,
                           to_string(lun),
                           not_null(hostgroup,'')]]
    hosts_dict: "{{ dict(array_info.purefa_info.hosts|
                         dict2items|
                         json_query(hosts_dict_query)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }},{{ item.1.volume }},{{ item.1.lun }},{{ item.1.hostgroup }}"
      loop: "{{ array_info.purefa_info.hosts|
                dict2items|
                subelements('value.volumes') }}"

    - debug:
        var: hosts_dict|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }},{{ item.1|join(',') }}"
      loop: "{{ hosts_dict|
                dict2items|
                subelements('value') }}"
```